# ESD - SMA connector

Tags: grounding, esd, fcc, tvs, ce

Suppose I have PCB in metal chassis with 2 SMA connectors mounted on it. Let's say  they are used for GSM and GPS.

How to protect against ESD and successfully pas FCC/CE? I couldn't find any TVS diode with such small capacitance at ~1.5GHz.

I've seen that some guys are using VVR on D+/D- signals on USB3.0. They should have capacitance significantly lower than 1pF. However, I am not sure about using them on this purpose.

Comment: A quick google for "gps antenna esd protection" yields numerous suitable products.

Comment: Thanks. I've googled "sma esd protection" without any success.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the electronic part distributors website and search "TVS diode" of "ESD suppressors" and find parts with ultra low capacitance. there are many choices for you. a sample Specifications as below:
[image: sample TVS diode specification for GPS/GNSS applications]